# K&R Exercise 4-3

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I just solved the exercise 4-10 - I replaced (unget/get)char with getline, but I can't add support for negative numbers. The reasoning is simple, if a char is a '-' and the character next to it is a digit or a decimal point we have a negative number. I don't know what I did wrong, first time i tryed something like this:

```
if(c != '-' && isdigit(line[lp])) {
    return c;
}
```

If we have a negative number, line 2 shouldn't be executed, and the array s will have as the first element a '-'.  However, I get an infinite loop and i can't find the problem.

This is the most relevant piece of code for this problem(especially the 4th if statement in getop).

```
#define MAXLINE 100
char line[MAXLINE];
int lp = 0;
int lineLength  = 0;
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int i, c;
    i = 0;
    while(--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if(c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
int getop(char s[]) {
    if(lp  == lineLength) {
        lineLength = getline(line, MAXLINE);
        lp = 0;
    }
    if(lineLength == 0)
        return EOF;
    char c;
    int i;
    printf("the execution is here\n");
    while((s[0] = c = line[lp++]) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        /* skip tabs an white spaces */;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if(!isdigit(c) && c != '.' && c != '-')
        return c;
    if(c == '-') {
        if(isdigit(line[lp]) || line[lp] == '.')
            /* nothing */;
       else
            return c;
    }
    i = 0;
    if(isdigit(c))
        while(isdigit((s[++i] = c = line[lp++])))
            ;
    if(c == '.')
        while(isdigit((s[++i] = c = line[lp++])))
            ;
    lp--;
    return NUMBER;
}
```

Comment: You might want to try using a symbolic debugger. Compile with `-g` and read a good gdb tutorial.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but this line is suspect to me: while((s[0] = c = line[lp++]) == ' ' || c == '\t').. I don't think in C you are guaranteed that c on the right of the logical or will be the content of the assignment on the left. The C language does not guarantee a specific behaviour with side-effect operations.

Comment: As an example to my earlier post: b=9; b=b+b=3; This could result in 6 or 12. This operation has a side-effect and the behaviour is not defined in C.

Comment: I saw that this technique is widely used in K&R. Btw, isn't asigment right to left associative?

Comment: @ephaitch: the `||` operator introduces a sequence point; all operations to its left will be complete, including side-effects, before the expression to its right is evaluated.  The `&&`, `?:` and `,` also introduce sequence points; other operators (notably including all the assignment operators) do not include sequence points.  The expression referred to is OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for clarifying. I forgot about sequence points with the operators you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to advance `lp` when you find a '-'.  The if's at the bottom of the function don't look for '-'.  You'll notice other digits (and the decimal point) advances `lp` before the function returns, so you need to copy that '-' sign to `s[]` (or store it in global flag) and increment `lp`, otherwise it just processes the same character over and over.

Stepping through the code in a debugger would help you see the problem as well, if you look at what `lp` does for positive numbers vs. negative numbers.